# Google tag manager export and import containers remotely

Tags: jenkins, import, google-analytics, export, google-tag-manager

I have two environments, dev and production(prd), and I have a google tag manager container for each environment.

When I deploy a new version in production, I also need to deploy the new tags from dev to prd container.

Is it possible to export and import a container remotely in google tag manager?

I use Jenkins to build and deploy new versions, I would like to start a pipeline flow in jenkins to deploy the dev environment tags to production environment automaticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really, unless you are happy to store them as individual tags/triggers/variables and import them separately via the API. Whole containers cannot be imported via the API. I know that Simo (Ahava, of [GTM tools](https://www.gtmtools.com/) fame) has a long standing feature request to add container imports to the API, but as of yet that hasn't happened.

(I am sure you could build a convoluted solution with a browser automation tool to emulate the manual import process, but I refuse to take this serious as a possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
Is it possible to export individual tags ... from a container and import each via the API?

Comment: I have never  created a complete container via the API (I just managed my more elaborate custom html tags and javascript variables via the API), but since containers have a create method in the API I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. The workflow will be a tad more elaborate (e.g. you need to select a workspace first and import to that). The documentation for the v2 API is rather good (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/create).